# How to fix 'No such module 'ReactNativeNavigation' error in swift ios project

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I just implemented the ReactNativeNavigation library to my ios project using a swift AppDelegate file and when I build the project I get the error: 'No such module 'ReactNativeNavigation'

I have tried to install a previous version of the package and also tried to enable 'Copy only when installing' in the package itself.

My AppDelegate.swift file's parts using the package

```swift
import ReactNativeNavigation

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource: nil)
    ReactNativeNavigation.bootstrap(jsCodeLocation, launchOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
  }
```

Has anyone met with this issue or knows how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation recently with swift and ReactNativeNavigation, I fixed it by:

- Removing "import ReactNativeNavigation" from AppDelegate.swift
- add `"#import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>"` to your "project"-Bridge-Header.h
- clear build cache and build again.